# My application crashed without any error, problem with for loop(?)

Tags: c

My teacher gave me a library that describes a single linked list. I am writing a main file to test it, and i ran into a very weird problem.

This is the header for the linked list library (There are more function, but i only putin the one i used):

```
#ifndef DSSINGLYLINKEDLIST_H
#define DSSINGLYLINKEDLIST_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct _SListEntry SListEntry;
typedef struct _SListIterator SListIterator;
typedef void *SListValue;

/**
 * Definition of a @ref SListIterator.
 */

struct _SListIterator {
    SListEntry **prevNext;
    SListEntry *current;
};
#define SLIST_NULL ((void *) 0)

typedef int (*SListCompareFunc)(SListValue value1, SListValue value2);
typedef int (*SListEqualFunc)(SListValue value1, SListValue value2);

SListEntry *slist_append(SListEntry **list, SListValue data);
SListValue slist_nthData(SListEntry *list, unsigned int n);
unsigned int slist_length(SListEntry *list);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* #ifndef DSSINGLYLINKEDLIST_H */
```

This is my .c file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "dssinglylinkedlist.h"

struct _SListEntry {
    SListValue data;
    SListEntry *next;
};

SListEntry *slist_append(SListEntry **list, SListValue data)
{
    /* Create new list entry */
    SListEntry *newEntry = malloc(sizeof(SListEntry));

    if (newEntry == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    newEntry->data = data;
    newEntry->next = NULL;

    /* Hooking into the list is different if the list is empty */
    SListEntry *rover;
    if (*list == NULL) {
        /* Create the start of the list */
        *list = newEntry;
    } else {
        /* Find the end of list */
        rover=*list;
        while (rover->next != NULL) {
            rover = rover->next;
        }

        /* Add to the end of list */
        rover->next = newEntry;
    }
    return newEntry;
}
SListValue slist_nthData(SListEntry *list, unsigned int n)
{
    /* Find the specified entry */
    SListEntry *entry = slist_nthEntry(list, n);

    /* If out of range, return NULL, otherwise return the data */
    if (entry == NULL) {
        return SLIST_NULL;
    } else {
        return entry->data;
    }
}
unsigned int slist_length(SListEntry *list)
{
    SListEntry *entry = list;
    unsigned int length = 0;

    while (entry != NULL) {
        /* Count the number of entries */
        ++length;
        entry = entry->next;
    }
    return length;
}
```

I think there's nothing wrong with these code.
I am writing a main using this library to store information of two polynomial:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "dssinglylinkedlist.h"

void printPolynomial(SListEntry*);

int main()
{
    SListEntry *poly1;
    int n;

    printf("Input n for poly1: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Input poly1: ");
    for (int i=0; i<=n; i++) {
        int  *temp = (int *) malloc(sizeof (int));
        scanf("%d", temp);
        slist_append(&poly1, temp);
    }

    printPolynomial(poly1);

    SListEntry *poly2;
    printf("Input n for poly2: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Input poly2: ");
//    for (int i=0; i<=n; i++) {
//        int  *temp = (int *) malloc(sizeof (int));
//        scanf("%d", temp);
//        slist_append(&poly2, temp);
//    }

//    printPolynomial(poly2);

    return 0;
}

void printPolynomial(SListEntry *list)
{
    int length = (int)slist_length(list);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int temp = *((int *)slist_nthData(list,(unsigned int)i));
        if (i >0 && temp >= 0) {
            printf("+");
        }
        printf("%d*x^%d", temp, length-i-1);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

So if i comments the second loop (after i print 'Input poly2', like i wrote above), i can still input my poly1 and print it. But if i un-comments it, my program crashes immediately when i append the first element of poly1.
What is the problem of my code?

Comment: Consider compiling with `-g` (debug), and running under a debugger. You are likely to find the problem(s).

Comment: poly1 and poly2 are uninitialized variables.

Comment: @dash-o i tried the debug mode of qt and it pointed to a line of code with segmentation fault. but that line work fine with only one poly. it only crash when i tried to input 2 poly

Comment: Did you try to initialize poly1 and poly2 with NULL?

Comment: @user5329483 thanks i just tried to initialize NULL. and it worked perfectly! I thought that i could just write struct like what i wrote without initialize anything. I must be wrong.